# PhantomJS page.open operation Delete on another domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs

I have domain A calling domain B to perform rest calls.

I am trying to send a rest api call from domain A that will delete an object on domain B. But the instead of sending operation DELETE, phantomjs sends operation POST.

I have tried the same with ajax, but i run into cross-domain not permitted issue.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var setting = {
    operation : "DELETE" };
page.open('http://domainB/id' , setting, function(status){
//do some stuff
});
```

Comment: Run with the `--web-security=false` commandline flag to remove cross-domain problems.

Comment: i have tried that, but did not help, getting "{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}-error" which is essentially cross domain denied error

Comment: Modern PhantomJS versions honour `--web-security=false` switch without problems. I've run cross-domain ajax from your previous question just yesterday with 2.1.1